# Sliding div offscreen

Tags: jquery-ui

As soon as im clicking on the div it is moving offscreen, but the second div isn't showed.Secondaly,I want this transition to happen on click of "click to slide two happen" on both.Here is the link to the fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/ykbgT/10110/

Any help would be great. Thanx in advance

```
$('.box').click(function() {
                            $('.box').each( function() {
                                if ($(this).offset().left < 0) {
                                    $(this).css("left", "150%");
                                }
                            });

                            $(this).animate({
                                 left: '-50%'
                             }, 500);

                             if ($(this).next().size() > 0) {
                                 $(this).next().animate({
                                     left: '50%'
                                 }, 500);
                             } else {
                                 $(this).prevAll().last().animate({
                                     left: '50%'
                                 }, 500);
                             }
                        });
```